# Scale in and out objects individually with pinch zoom

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pinchzoom

Hi i have a script with name lean touch and the other one with name simple scale. i attach the lean touch script with empty object and and drag the simple scale script on object which i want to scale and its working perfectly. the problem is that if i have 2 objects in the scene at a time and both have "simple scale" script then both are scale in and out at the same time.The thing which i want is if i want to scale cube then it should be cube, and if i want to scale sphere then only sphere thanks.
Here's "Lean touch" script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Lean
// If you add this component to your scene, then it will convert all mouse and touch data into easy to use data
[ExecuteInEditMode]
[AddComponentMenu("Lean/Touch")]
public class LeanTouch : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This contains the current LeanTouch instance
    public static LeanTouch Instance;

    // This list contains all currently active fingers (including simulated ones)
    public static List<LeanFinger> Fingers = new List<LeanFinger>();

    // This list contains all currently inactive fingers (e.g. this allows for pooling and tapping)
    public static List<LeanFinger> InactiveFingers = new List<LeanFinger>();

    // This contains the combined screen position delta of all fingers
    public static Vector2 DragDelta;

    // This contains the screen position delta of a single finger (if more than one finger is pressed down, then this value will be reset to 0,0)
    public static Vector2 SoloDragDelta;

    // This contains the combined screen position delta of multiple fingers (if only one finger is pressed down, then this value will be reset to 0,0)
    public static Vector2 MultiDragDelta;

    // This contains the average screen twist delta of multiple fingers in degrees (this requires at least two fingers to be pressed down)
    public static float TwistDegrees;

    // This contains the average screen twist delta of multiple fingers in radians (this requires at least two fingers to be pressed down)
    public static float TwistRadians;

    // This contains the average screen pinch scale of multiple fingers (this requires at least two fingers to be pressed down)
    public static float PinchScale = 1.0f;

    // This gets fired when a finger begins touching the screen (LeanFinger = The current finger)
    public static System.Action<LeanFinger> OnFingerDown;

    // This gets fired every frame a finger is touching the screen (LeanFinger = The current finger)
    public static System.Action<LeanFinger> OnFingerSet;

    // This gets fired when a finger stops touching the screen (LeanFinger = The current finger)
    public static System.Action<LeanFinger> OnFingerUp;

    // This gets fired when a finger moves across the screen (LeanFinger = The current finger)
    public static System.Action<LeanFinger> OnFingerDrag;

    // This gets fired when a finger taps the screen (this is when a finger begins and stops touching the screen within the 'TapThreshold' time) (LeanFinger = The current finger)
    public static System.Action<LeanFinger> OnFingerTap;

    // This gets fired when a finger swipes the screen (this is when a finger begins and stops touching the screen within the 'TapThreshold' time, and also moves more than the 'SwipeThreshold' distance) (LeanFinger = The current finger)
    public static System.Action<LeanFinger> OnFingerSwipe;

    // This gets fired when a finger begins being held on the screen (this is when a finger has been set for longer than the 'HeldThreshold' time) (LeanFinger = The current finger)
    public static System.Action<LeanFinger> OnFingerHeldDown;

    // This gets fired when a finger is held on the screen (this is when a finger has been set for longer than the 'HeldThreshold' time) (LeanFinger = The current finger)
    public static System.Action<LeanFinger> OnFingerHeldSet;

    // This gets fired when a finger stops being held on the screen (this is when a finger has been set for longer than the 'HeldThreshold' time) (LeanFinger = The current finger)
    public static System.Action<LeanFinger> OnFingerHeldUp;

    // This gets fired when at least one finger taps the screen (int = Highest Finger Count)
    public static System.Action<int> OnMultiTap;

    // This gets fired when a finger moves across the screen (Vector2 = DragDelta)
    public static System.Action<Vector2> OnDrag;

    // This gets fired when a single finger moves across the screen (if more than one finger is pressed down, then this value will not get fired) (Vector2 = SoloDragDelta)
    public static System.Action<Vector2> OnSoloDrag;

    // This gets fired when a multiple fingers moves across the screen (if only one finger is pressed down, then this value will not get fired) (Vector2 = MultiDragDelta)
    public static System.Action<Vector2> OnMultiDrag;

    // This gets fired when a pinch gesture occurs (float = PinchScale)
    public static System.Action<float> OnPinch;

    // This gets fired when a twist gesture occurs (float = TwistDegrees)
    public static System.Action<float> OnTwistDegrees;

    // This gets fired when a twist gesture occurs (float = TwistRadians)
    public static System.Action<float> OnTwistRadians;

    // This allows you to set how many seconds are required between a finger down/up for a tap to be registered
    public float TapThreshold = 0.5f;

    // This allows you to set how many pixels of movement (relative to the ReferenceDpi) are required within the TapThreshold for a swipe to be triggered
    public float SwipeThreshold = 50.0f;

    // This allows you to set how many seconds a finger must be held down for it to be regarded as being held down
    public float HeldThreshold = 1.0f;

    // This allows you to set the default DPI you want the input scaling to be based on
    public int ReferenceDpi = 200;

    // This allows you to enable recording of finger movements
    public bool RecordFingers = true;

    // This allows you to set the amount of pixels a finger must move for another snapshot to be stored
    public float RecordThreshold = 5.0f;

    // This allows you to set the maximum amount of seconds that can be recorded, 0 = unlimited
    public float RecordLimit;

    // This allows you to simulate multi touch inputs on devices that don't support them (e.g. desktop)
    public bool SimulateMultiFingers = true;

    // This allows you to set which key is required to simulate multi key twisting
    public KeyCode PinchTwistKey = KeyCode.LeftControl;

    // This allows you to set which key is required to simulate multi key dragging
    public KeyCode MultiDragKey = KeyCode.LeftAlt;

    // This allows you to set which texture will be used to show the simulated fingers
    public Texture2D FingerTexture;

    // This stores the highest mouse button index
    private static int highestMouseButton = 7;

    // This stores how many fingers were touching the screen last frame
    private int lastFingerCount;

    // This stores how many seconds at least one finger has been touching the screen
    private float multiFingerTime;

    // This stores how many fingers at most were held during the multiFingerTime
    private int multiFingerCount;

    // If you multiply this value with any other pixel delta (e.g. DragDelta), then it will become device resolution independant
public static float ScalingFactor
    {
        get
        {
            var scalingFactor = 1.0f;
            var referenceDpi  = 200;

            // Grab the current reference DPI, if it exists
            if (Instance != null)
            {
                referenceDpi = Instance.ReferenceDpi;
            }

            // If this screen has a known DPI, scale the value based on it
            if (Screen.dpi > 0 && referenceDpi > 0)
            {
                scalingFactor = Mathf.Sqrt(referenceDpi) / Mathf.Sqrt(Screen.dpi);
            }

            return scalingFactor;
        }
    }

    // This will return the DragDelta after it's been scaled to current DPI
    public static Vector2 ScaledDragDelta
    {
        get
        {
            return DragDelta * ScalingFactor;
        }
    }

    // This will return the SoloDragDelta after it's been scaled to current DPI
    public static Vector2 ScaledSoloDragDelta
    {
        get
        {
            return SoloDragDelta * ScalingFactor;
        }
    }

    // This will return the MultiDragDelta after it's been scaled to current DPI
    public static Vector2 ScaledMultiDragDelta
    {
        get
        {
            return MultiDragDelta * ScalingFactor;
        }
    }

    // Returns true if any mouse button is pressed
    public static bool AnyMouseButtonSet
    {
        get
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < highestMouseButton; i++)
            {
                if (Input.GetMouseButton(i) == true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    // This will return true if the mouse or any finger is currently using the GUI
    public static bool GuiInUse
    {
        get
        {
            // Legacy GUI in use?
            if (GUIUtility.hotControl > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            // New GUI in use?
            for (var i = Fingers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (Fingers[i].IsOverGui == true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    // The center point of all fingers, or default
    public static Vector2 GetCenterOfFingers()
    {
        var total       = Vector2.zero;
        var fingerCount = Fingers.Count;

        if (fingerCount > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < fingerCount; i++)
            {
                total += Fingers[i].ScreenPosition;
            }

            total /= fingerCount;
        }

        return total;
    }
// The last center point of all fingers, or default
    public static Vector2 GetLastCenterOfFingers()
    {
        var total       = Vector2.zero;
        var fingerCount = Fingers.Count;

        if (fingerCount > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < fingerCount; i++)
            {
                total += Fingers[i].LastScreenPosition;
            }

            total /= fingerCount;
        }

        return total;
    }

    // This will return the average distance between all fingers and the reference point
    public static float GetAverageFingerDistance(Vector2 referencePoint)
    {
        var total       = 0.0f;
        var fingerCount = Fingers.Count;

        if (fingerCount > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < fingerCount; i++)
            {
                total += Fingers[i].GetDistance(referencePoint);
            }

            total /= fingerCount;
        }

        return total;
    }

    // This will return the last average distance between all fingers and the reference point
    public static float GetLastAverageFingerDistance(Vector2 referencePoint)
    {
        var total       = 0.0f;
        var fingerCount = Fingers.Count;

        if (fingerCount > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < fingerCount; i++)
            {
                total += Fingers[i].GetLastDistance(referencePoint);
            }

            total /= fingerCount;
        }

        return total;
    }

    // This allows you to drag an object on screen by a change in screen position
    public static void MoveObject(Transform transform, Vector2 deltaPosition, Camera camera = null)
    {
        if (transform != null)
        {
            if (deltaPosition.x != 0.0f || deltaPosition.y != 0.0f)
            {
                var rectTransform = transform as RectTransform;

                // If this is RectTransform then modify the anchoredPosition
                if (rectTransform != null)
                {
                    rectTransform.anchoredPosition += deltaPosition;
                }
                // If this is Transform then modify the position
                else
                {
                    transform.position = MoveObject(transform.position, deltaPosition, camera);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Vector3 MoveObject(Vector3 worldPosition, Vector2 deltaPosition, Camera camera = null)
    {
        if (camera == null) camera = Camera.main;

        if (camera != null)
        {
            // Find current screen position of world position
            var screenPosition = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(worldPosition);

            // Modify screen position
            screenPosition += (Vector3)deltaPosition;

            // Write new world position
            worldPosition = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition);
        }

        return worldPosition;
    }

    // This allows you to rotate an object on screen by a change in screen rotation
    public static void RotateObject(Transform transform, float deltaRotation, Camera camera = null)
    {
        if (transform != null && deltaRotation != 0.0f)
        {
            transform.rotation = RotateObject(transform.rotation, deltaRotation, camera);
        }
    }

    public static Quaternion RotateObject(Quaternion worldRotation, float deltaRotation, Camera camera = null)
    {
        if (deltaRotation != 0.0f)
        {
            if (camera == null) camera = Camera.main;

            if (camera != null)
            {
                worldRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(deltaRotation, camera.transform.forward) * worldRotation;
            }
        }

        return worldRotation;
    }

    // This allows you to scale an object by a change in pinch scale
public static void ScaleObject(Transform transform, float scale)
    {
        if (transform != null && scale != 1.0f)
        {
            transform.localScale *= scale;
        }
    }

    // This allows you to scale an object by a change in pinch scale, relative to a point on the screen
    public static void ScaleObjectRelative(Transform transform, float scale, Vector2 referencePoint, Camera camera = null)
    {
        if (transform != null && scale != 1.0f)
        {
            if (camera == null) camera = Camera.main;

            if (camera != null)
            {
                // Find screen position of transform
                var localPosition = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

                // Scale screen position away from referencePoint
                localPosition.x = referencePoint.x + (localPosition.x - referencePoint.x) * scale;
                localPosition.y = referencePoint.y + (localPosition.y - referencePoint.y) * scale;

                // Update position
                transform.position = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(localPosition);

                // Scale up
                transform.localScale *= scale;
            }
        }
    }

    // This allows you to rotate an object on screen by a change in screen rotation, relative to a point on the screen
    public static void RotateObjectRelative(Transform transform, float deltaRotation, Vector2 referencePoint, Camera camera = null)
    {
        if (transform != null && deltaRotation != 0.0f)
        {
            if (camera == null) camera = Camera.main;

            if (camera != null)
            {
                transform.RotateAround(camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(referencePoint), camera.transform.forward, deltaRotation);
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnEnable()
    {
        // Make sure there's only one LeanTouch active in the scene
        if (Instance != null && Instance != this)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Your scene already contains a " + typeof(LeanTouch).Name + ", destroying the old one...");

            DestroyImmediate(Instance.gameObject);
        }

        Instance = this;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        // Set the finger texture?
        if (FingerTexture == null)
        {
            var guids = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.FindAssets("FingerVisualization t:texture2d");

            if (guids.Length > 0)
            {
                var path = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guids[0]);

                FingerTexture = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath(path) as Texture2D;
            }
        }
#endif
    }

    protected virtual void Update()
    {
        UpdateAllInputs();
    }

    protected virtual void OnGUI()
    {
        // Show simulated multi fingers?
        if (FingerTexture != null && Input.touchCount == 0 && Fingers.Count > 1)
        {
            for (var i = Fingers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Fingers[i].Show(FingerTexture);
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateAllInputs()
    {
        UpdateFingers();
        UpdateMultiTap();
        UpdateGestures();
        UpdateEvents();
    }

    private void UpdateFingers()
    {
        // Age inactive fingers
        for (var i = InactiveFingers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            InactiveFingers[i].Age += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        }

        // Reset finger data
        for (var i = Fingers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var finger = Fingers[i];

            // Was this set to up last time?
            if (finger.Up == true)
            {
                // Make finger inactive
                Fingers.RemoveAt(i); InactiveFingers.Add(finger);

                // Reset age so we can time how long it's been inactive
                finger.Age = 0.0f;

                // Pool old snapshots
                finger.ClearSnapshots();
            }
            else
            {
                finger.LastSet            = finger.Set;
                finger.LastHeldSet        = finger.HeldSet;
                finger.LastScreenPosition = finger.ScreenPosition;

                finger.Set     = false;
                finger.HeldSet = false;
                finger.Tap     = false;
            }
        }

        // Update real fingers
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
            {
                var touch = Input.GetTouch(i);

                AddFinger(touch.fingerId, touch.position);
            }
        }
        // If there are no real touches, simulate some from the mouse?
        else if (AnyMouseButtonSet == true)
        {
            var screen        = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
            var mousePosition = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition;

            // Is the mouse within the screen?
            if (screen.Contains(mousePosition) == true)
            {
                AddFinger(0, mousePosition);

                // Simulate pinch & twist?
                if (SimulateMultiFingers == true)
                {
                    if (Input.GetKey(PinchTwistKey) == true)
                    {
                        var center = new Vector2(Screen.width * 0.5f, Screen.height * 0.5f);

                        AddFinger(1, center - (mousePosition - center));
                    }
                    // Simulate multi drag?
                    else if (Input.GetKey(MultiDragKey) == true)
                    {
                        AddFinger(1, mousePosition);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Go through all fingers
        for (var i = Fingers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var finger = Fingers[i];

            // Up?
            if (finger.Up == true)
            {
                // Tap?
                if (finger.Age <= TapThreshold && finger.ScaledTotalDeltaMagnitude < SwipeThreshold)
                {
                    finger.Tap       = true;
                    finger.TapCount += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    finger.TapCount = 0;
                }
            }
            // Down?
            else if (finger.Down == false)
            {
                // Age it
                finger.Age += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;

                // Held?
                if (finger.Age >= HeldThreshold)
                {
                    finger.HeldSet = true;
                }
            }

            finger.TotalDeltaMagnitude += finger.DeltaScreenPosition.magnitude;
        }
    }

    // This handles the OnMultiTap event
    private void UpdateMultiTap()
    {
        var fingerCount = Fingers.Count;

        // At least one finger set?
        if (fingerCount >= 1)
        {
            multiFingerTime += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
            multiFingerCount = Mathf.Max(multiFingerCount, fingerCount);

            // Did this just begin?
            if (lastFingerCount == 0)
            {
                multiFingerTime  = 0.0f;
                multiFingerCount = 0;
            }
        }

        // All fingers released?
        if (fingerCount == 0 && lastFingerCount > 0)
        {
            // Was at least one finger tapped?
            if (multiFingerTime <= TapThreshold)
            {
                if (OnMultiTap != null) OnMultiTap(multiFingerCount);
            }
        }

        lastFingerCount = fingerCount;
    }

    // Read finger data to find any gestures
    private void UpdateGestures()
    {
        var fingerCount = Fingers.Count;

        // Reset values
        DragDelta      = Vector3.zero;
        SoloDragDelta  = Vector2.zero;
        MultiDragDelta = Vector2.zero;
        PinchScale     = 1.0f;
        TwistRadians   = 0.0f;
        TwistDegrees   = 0.0f;

        // Fingers?
        if (fingerCount > 0)
        {
            // Drag delta
            for (var i = 0; i < fingerCount; i++)
            {
                DragDelta += Fingers[i].DeltaScreenPosition;
            }

            // Solo?
            if (fingerCount == 1)
            {
                // Drag
                SoloDragDelta = Fingers[0].DeltaScreenPosition;
            }
            // Multi?
            else
            {
                var lastCenter   = GetLastCenterOfFingers();
                var center       = GetCenterOfFingers();
                var lastDistance = GetLastAverageFingerDistance(lastCenter);
                var distance     = GetAverageFingerDistance(center);

                // Pinch?
                if (lastDistance > 0.0f && distance > 0.0f)
                {
                    PinchScale = distance / lastDistance;
                }

                // Twist?
                for (var i = 0; i < fingerCount; i++)
                {
                    TwistRadians += Fingers[i].GetDeltaRadians(lastCenter, center);
                    TwistDegrees += Fingers[i].GetDeltaDegrees(lastCenter, center);
                }

                // Drag
                for (var i = 0; i < fingerCount; i++)
                {
                    MultiDragDelta += Fingers[i].DeltaScreenPosition;
                }
            }

            // Scale values
            TwistRadians   /= fingerCount;
            TwistDegrees   /= fingerCount;
            DragDelta      /= fingerCount;
            MultiDragDelta /= fingerCount;
        }
    }

    // Fire events if there are any listeners
    private void UpdateEvents()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Fingers.Count; i++)
        {
            var finger = Fingers[i];

            if (finger.Down     == true && OnFingerDown     != null) OnFingerDown(finger);
            if (finger.Set      == true && OnFingerSet      != null) OnFingerSet(finger);
            if (finger.Up       == true && OnFingerUp       != null) OnFingerUp(finger);
            if (finger.Tap      == true && OnFingerTap      != null) OnFingerTap(finger);
            if (finger.HeldDown == true && OnFingerHeldDown != null) OnFingerHeldDown(finger);
            if (finger.HeldSet  == true && OnFingerHeldSet  != null) OnFingerHeldSet(finger);
            if (finger.HeldUp   == true && OnFingerHeldUp   != null) OnFingerHeldUp(finger);

            // Dragged?
            if (finger.DeltaScreenPosition != Vector2.zero)
            {
                if (OnFingerDrag != null) OnFingerDrag(finger);
            }

            // Swiped?
            if (finger.Up == true && finger.GetScaledSnapshotDelta(TapThreshold).magnitude >= SwipeThreshold)
            {
                if (OnFingerSwipe != null) OnFingerSwipe(finger);
            }
        }

        if (DragDelta      != Vector2.zero && OnDrag      != null) OnDrag(DragDelta);
        if (SoloDragDelta  != Vector2.zero && OnSoloDrag  != null) OnSoloDrag(SoloDragDelta);
        if (MultiDragDelta != Vector2.zero && OnMultiDrag != null) OnMultiDrag(MultiDragDelta);
        if (PinchScale     != 1.0f         && OnPinch     != null) OnPinch(PinchScale);

        if (TwistDegrees != 0.0f)
        {
            if (OnTwistDegrees != null) OnTwistDegrees(TwistDegrees);
            if (OnTwistRadians != null) OnTwistRadians(TwistRadians);
        }
    }

    // Add a finger based on index, or return the existing one
    private void AddFinger(int index, Vector2 screenPosition)
    {
        var finger = Fingers.Find(t => t.Index == index);

        // No finger found?
        if (finger == null)
        {
            var inactiveIndex = InactiveFingers.FindIndex(t => t.Index == index);

            // Use inactive finger?
            if (inactiveIndex >= 0)
            {
                finger = InactiveFingers[inactiveIndex]; InactiveFingers.RemoveAt(inactiveIndex);

                // Inactive for too long?
                if (finger.Age > TapThreshold)
                {
                    finger.TapCount = 0;
                }

                // Reset values
                finger.Age         = 0.0f;
                finger.LastSet     = false;
                finger.Set         = false;
                finger.LastHeldSet = false;
                finger.HeldSet     = false;
                finger.Tap         = false;
            }
            // Create new finger?
            else
            {
                finger = new LeanFinger();

                finger.Index = index;
            }

            finger.StartScreenPosition = screenPosition;
            finger.LastScreenPosition  = screenPosition;
            finger.ScreenPosition      = screenPosition;
            finger.StartedOverGui      = finger.IsOverGui;
            finger.TotalDeltaMagnitude = 0.0f;

            Fingers.Add(finger);
        }

        finger.Set            = true;
        finger.ScreenPosition = screenPosition;


        // Record?
        if (RecordFingers == true)
        {
            // Too many snapshots?
            if (RecordLimit > 0.0f)
            {
                if (finger.SnapshotDuration > RecordLimit)
                {
                    var removeCount = finger.GetLowerSnapshotIndex(finger.Age - RecordLimit);

                    finger.ClearSnapshots(removeCount);
                }
            }

            // Record snapshot?
            if (RecordThreshold > 0.0f)
            {
                if (finger.Snapshots.Count == 0 || finger.LastSnapshotDelta.magnitude >= RecordThreshold)
                {
                    finger.RecordSnapshot();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                finger.RecordSnapshot();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And Here's "Simple scale" script:

```
using UnityEngine;
// This script will rotate and scale the GameObject based on finger gestures
public class SimpleScale : MonoBehaviour
{
protected virtual void LateUpdate()
{
// This will rotate the current transform based on a multi finger twist gesture
//  Lean.LeanTouch.RotateObject(transform, Lean.LeanTouch.TwistDegrees);

    // This will scale the current transform based on a multi finger pinch gesture
Lean.LeanTouch.ScaleObject(transform, Lean.LeanTouch.PinchScale);

} }
```

Comment: Sounds like your objects are sharing the same instance of the scaling script. Each object needs to have its own instance of the script - or the script only wants to be attached to a single object at a time.

Comment: please edit my code to solve my problem if you can thanks.